# What is the advantage of using package in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, package

Currently I am using the Oracle 10 g and I found there is Package where user can write stored procedures,I have few questions regarding this.

Why we need package in Oracle?

What is its actual use and advantages of using it?

Oracle package alternative in MySql and Sql Server DBMS?

Comment: I saw the answer pros and cons it just answered one of my question.I have asked three question.Also I wanted to know the How it distinguish Oracle from the other DBMS?

Answer (score 1):

Its a theoretical question.

When you build a package, you decide which of the package elements are public (can be referenced outside of the package) and which are private (available only within the package itself). You also can restrict access to the package to only the specification. In this way, you use the package to hide the implementation details of your programs.

And we do not have package concept in SQL Server or MySQL.

To understand more please follow below link

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/09_packs.htm

Answer (score -1):

A package is a logical group of procedures and functions. Generally you can think about packages as a "class" in Java/c++ (if you are familiar with OOP).
MySQL and MSSQL does not have such term but in general this is not a problem as you can do the same thing without packages.